# How to Prevent Access Violating Reading When Using Pointers of Classes

Tags: c++, access-violation

I currently have two classes in which I would like to communicate with each other. I have a class called stack which may have several instances of so I would like to tell my other class, Map, how many instances of stack there would be. I have passed the memory address of the Map class to stack and in its constructor I am wanting to use the memory address' method called AddSize() which increments an int variable by one so the Map Class knows how many Sizes to expect, (I am planning on building an array).

The Issue I am having is Unhanded Exception Access Reading Violating at Run Time.

I guess I will show some of the code. Thank you for taking the time to read my question.

Retrieves the Given Map Pointer as it is stores in Stack's datamembers and it uses the pointer to attempt to use its methods. (Head is assiociated with a different Array of Nodes.

```
Stack<DT>::Stack(DT * MapPointer)
{

    head = NULL;
    Map<DT> * Pointer = MapAddress;
    Pointer->AddSize();
    cout << "Stack Initalised. Size Is: " << sizeof(DT) << " Address Is: " << &head << endl;

}
```

Below is the Map Class and it is bare because I have only started working on it. I plan to add functionality like the Map type in STL.

```
template<typename DT>
class Map{

private:    
    Node<DT> * head; //Top

public:
    int size;
    Map(){      
        cout << "Map Initalised" << endl;

    }
    void Insert(DT*);
    void Add(DT*);
    void AddSize();
};

template<typename DT>
void Map<DT>::Insert(DT * address){

}

template<typename DT>
void Map<DT>::Add(DT * address){

}

template<typename DT>
void Map<DT>::AddSize(){
    size++;
    cout << size << endl;
}
```

The runtime error only occurs if size is mentioned, if I display text I have wrote it will not throw a runtime error. Does it have something to do with encapsulation? I have attempted to use the friend function however to no avail.

Comment: As for your title: Just don't use raw pointers in C++. There are only rare use cases that would justify to use raw pointers. Use references or smart pointers instead.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: "How to Prevent Access Violating Reading When Using Pointers of Classes" null check them? Also as already suggested you should look into smart pointers if you are on C++11... or have access to a library that contains them.

Comment: What is `MapAddress`?  And your `Map` constructor does not initialize any of your class members.

Comment: *I plan to add functionality like the Map type in STL* -- I have to ask.  Why?  What's wrong with just using `std::map`?

Comment: @George _"null check them?"_ That won't help for all the cases. There are such nasty things like _dangling pointerss_ which won't be `NULL` or `nullptr`.